# How to share a library between a WCF Service Application and a UWP app?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, win-universal-app

It's kind of a strange question but here is my problem:

I have an Universal Windows App, a shared framework (using a library/shared project) and a WCF Service Application.

Because I want to include the DataContracts in my framework and using these in my WCF Service Application and in my Universal Windows App I tried a Portable Library with .Net 4.6 and Universal Windows 10 (using ChannelFactory - I know, i could use a proxy, but i don't want to (not important for this problem)).

[image: Image of portable library /w .Net 4.6 and Win 10]

The problem:
[image: System.Runtime.Serialization not supported]

It's not possible to use `System.Runtime.Serialization`, but it can be used in Universal Windows Libraries (I can't add them to the WCF Service Application) and in Portable Libraries with Windows 8.1 and .Net 4.5.1. I think that's a bug.

I solved this problem using a Shared Project and BAMM new problem.
 I can't use class diagrams (don't know why?) and I also won't use the UML class diagrams because since VS13 it can't generate the Diagram from Code (even if it would be possible - it doesn't update automatically... why???)

Comment: If it's the wrong community please inform me ^^

Comment: Have you tried runtime components?

Comment: Yes, but it can't be added to a WCF Service Application (only to Universal Windows Apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use .net 4.6 in your PCL, you need to reference System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll as well.
You can download the portable reference assemblies for .net 4.6 here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727

Answer (score 0):

Change the Framework Version of your PCL to 4.5.1 and it should work for both, the Universal App and WCF Service Application.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your Problem now... If you really want to use .net 4.6 in your PCL, you need to reference System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll as well. You can download the portable reference assemblies for .net 4.6 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what i need :)

Comment: I reposted with a new answer. You can now mark it as answered if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are including System.Runtime.Seralization in you assembly references AND that you have it in your using statement?

Comment: I can't add the System.Runtime.Seralization. The references can't be changed in Portable Libraries